# Content provider not returning data in release build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have created 2 Apps. App 1 (Implemented content provider and provides data) & App 2 (Consumes data from app1 via content resolver).

In App 1 , I have declared content provider

```
 <provider
            android:name=".core.info.myContentProvider.DataProvider"
            android:authorities="com.test.mytest.android"
            android:exported="true"
            android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

App 2 consumes data like

```
val cur = contentResolver.query(
        Uri.parse("content://com.test.mytest.android/users"),
        null, null, null, null
    )
```

**Problem :** It's working fine if my App 1 is Debug build. When App 1 is installed as release build , App 2 is unable to access data contentResolver.query returns null. Any idea on this?

Comment: android:enabled="true" ?

Comment: And try without protection level attribute.

Comment: Hey
Have you solved this?
I have encountered a similar issue.